# Non-homeomorphic (?) subspaces of Euclidean plane

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y_1 = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I((0,0),(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^2}))$ and $Y_2 = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I((0,0),(1,\frac{1}{n})) \cup I((0,0),(1,0))$ where $I$ denotes line segment in Euclidean space.

I'm inclined to believe, these spaces with natural topology are NOT homeomorphic (just a hunch). But I have absolutely no idea how to show that... When you draw $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ they look like pretty much the same, they're both closed, compact, connected, path-connected, removing points leaves them topologically identical.

What do you think?

Comment: What is a closed interval between two points in the plane? Is it a line segment?

Comment: Yeah, yeah, that's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: @Jules : I am not sure about 'removing points'. If we remove $(0,0)$, then the two would have different numbers of connected components?

Comment: They are not homeomorphic: The first one is locally connected and the second one is not.

Comment: Would we? I thought both would still have countably many connected components since each line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1/n)$ (without the $(0,0)$ itself) is such a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement of any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $Y_1$ is a finite collection of line segments, while there are neighbourhoods of $(0,0)\in Y_2$ where that isn't the case.

One other property that differentiated them is that $Y_2$ isn't locally connected. For instance any small enough neighbourhood of $(1/2,0)$ consists of infinitely many line segments.

Comment: Oh, that's good, wouldn't have thought of it. Thanks ;)

Comment: To complete the first argument, you should also note that any possible homeomorphism would have to map any 'infinite' cut-point from one space to an infinite cut-point in the other - in both cases the only infinite cut-point is $(0,0)$. You can then deduce that they should have consistent families of neighbourhoods.